# String to byte[] and vice versa?

Tags: c#, string, binary, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET String to byte Array C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c)

How do I convert String to byte[] array and vice versa? I need strings to be stored in some binary storage. Please show example in both directions. And one more thing: each string maybe bigger than 90Kb.

Comment: That question has a rather misleading accepted answer, depending on the behavior of the runtime serialization output, which is certainly not cross-language-compatible.  Therefore I am not going to vote to close as a duplicate.  Using a proper encoding, like UTF-8, is a much better approach.

Comment: @cdhowie: agreed. "Rather misleading" is a polite way to put it. :)

Comment: Presumably that's why there is a better answer with higher votes just underneath.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to use UTF-8 encoding:

```
// string to byte[]
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someString);

// byte[] to string
string anotherString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 8):

Before you march off and use one of the examples someone's already given you should be aware that there is, in general, no unique mapping between a string and a sequence of bytes. How the string is mapped to binary (and vice versa) is determined by the [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) that you use. Joel Spolsky wrote an [awesome article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on this subject.

When decoding binary to get a string, you need to use the same encoding as was used to produce the binary in the first place, otherwise you'll run into problems.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class.

Comment: 1+ for link to docs

Answer (score 1):

[How do I get a consistent byte representation of strings in C# without manually specifying an encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c)