# Convert a string to byte[] for socket

Tags: c#, string, sockets, ftp, byte

I am writing a simple ftp client with c#.
I am not pro in c#. Is there any way to convert string to byte[] and write it to the socket?
for example for introducing username this is the socket content:

```
5553455220736f726f7573680d0a
```

and ASCII equivalent is:

```
USER soroush
```

I want a method to convert string. Something like this:

```
public byte[] getByte(string str)
{
    byte[] ret;
    //some code here
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891438/convert-string-to-byte-array

Comment: Why I got -1 vote down ?

Comment: Other duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056336/c-sharp-byte-byte-array-to-unicode-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318693/string-to-byte-and-vice-versa -1 for "does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// C# to convert a string to a byte array.
public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
{
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8; //or below line
    //System.Text.UTF8Encoding  encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(str);
}
```

and

```
// C# to convert a byte array to a string.
byte [] dBytes = ...
string str;
Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8; //or below line 
//System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
str = enc.GetString(dBytes);
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new UTF8Encoding each time rather than using `Encoding.UTF8`?

Comment: @JonSkeet - not aware of that let me check on msdn...and will update answer

Comment: @PranayRana couldn't you just return `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);`? You shouldn't need to copy the encoding to another variable.

Comment: @Bridge - ok thanks for the infomation...that can be achievable but is that creates and difference

Answer (score 5):

Try

`byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);`