# how to convert from string to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, c++, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET String to byte Array C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c)

Hi,

How can I convert from string:My text into { 0x38, 0x41, 0x45... }and so on. I would like an example in both c++ and c# (.net) code. THX