# how to convert from string to hex

Tags: c#, .net, c++, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how to convert from string to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041381/how-to-convert-from-string-to-byte)
>   [C++ convert string to hexadecimal and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381614/c-convert-string-to-hexadecimal-and-vice-versa)

Hi
I have a string value that I would like to convert into hex values. How can I do that
I would like to have something like this:

```
new byte[] {0x44, 0x52, 0x36.. and so on.
```

Need some help. THX!!

Can someone give me an example in c# and c++? THX!!