# MVC3 Download Excel Workbook from CSV data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, export-to-excel, filecontentresult

I've got a set of data that exists in memory in a CSV format.  I have this method in my controller:

```
     public FileContentResult ItemsAsExcelExport(){
         var model = _itemService.GetExcelExportModel();
        return new FileContentResult(model.CSVData, model.MimeType){FileDownloadName = model.FileName};
     }
```

The problem here is that my model.CSVData property returns a simple comma delimited set of values.  I'm not sure how I can satisfy the fileContents argument of the FileContentResult contructor. It's asking for a byte array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question [How do I get a consistent byte representation of strings in C# without manually specifying an encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c)

The solution is

```
  byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (myString);
```

Comment: Will this alter my data at all?

Comment: No, of course not. It simply converts your string into array of bytes. Nothing more