# Converting string, etc. into bytes and byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, type-conversion

Is there a static method for converting a string, int, etc. into a byte/byte array?

I already know about this method:

```
    public static byte[] FromString(string Input)
    {
        ASCIIEncoding ByteEncoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        return ByteEncoder.GetBytes(Input);
    }
```

But i was wondering if there is anything better.  Would it be a problem if I made a static instance of the ASCII encoder to use?

Also - in terms of performance - how does the ASCII conversion method above compare with doing it via a for loop or other such methods that are multi-line solutions?

Also - when should I use ASCII vs. Unicode?

William

Comment: Those multiple questions up there should each be their own question.

Comment: You shouldn't post multiple questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET String to byte Array C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no static method. There are, however, static instances of `Encoding`.

`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`.

In terms of performance, you should trust the BCL. It's been written carefully so you should expect near-optimal code, and certainly better handling of all the edge cases one does not always think about.

Comment: Interesting that the class is marked as not being thread safe for instance members though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx.  I'd advise creating new instances in multi-threaded scenarios just to be safe.

Comment: It would be clearer to use `Encoding.ASCII` - there's no need to use `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII`.

Comment: @ChrisShain: No, these are definitely thread-safe. There really is no need to create new instances. There's no mutable state in an Encoding. There *is* in an Encoder/Decoder, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet I figured, just don't see any documentation of that.  Always makes me nervous.

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed, it seems autocompletion lead me the wrong way!

Comment: @JonSkeet Why should be clearer use the Encoding class instead of ASCIIEncoding?

Comment: @Fuex: Because it's declared on `Encoding` - if you write `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII` it *looks* like it's declared on `ASCIIEncoding`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, I see your point, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

What's about [ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.getbytes%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx).  It supports integers and floats.  Also [Encoding.UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) for strings.

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(4); // Int32

System.Text.Enconding.UTF8.GetBytes("My string"); // String
```

You probably want to support unicode, even if you don't use it.  Try UTF8 instead of ascii so you can support extended characters if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

The main questions have been answered, but to answer the final one, use Unicode if you will ever have to support non-English character sets and symbols.  If you are using the English subset of global characters, then stick with ASCII (although I prefer UTF-8.  Also, this is a good opportunity to share the wisdom of Spolsky.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html  -Extremely good article.