# ntext in ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: c#, sql-server, code-first, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

how can i have nText datatype in ServiceStack.OrmLite Code first ?

```
public class Email
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long ID { get; set; }


    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string From { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; } 

    nText =>
    public string Body { get; set; } 

}
```

if i use string datatype , ormlite generate nVarchar(8000) in database

i need more than 8000 character for data

Comment: C#'s string datatype is fine for ntext.  It can contain unicode characters, and can hold an arbitrary length string.

Comment: Don't use `text`, `ntext` or `image` for new development -- these data types are [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Use, respectively, `varchar(MAX)`, `nvarchar(MAX)`, and `varbinary(MAX)`. You'll need to consult your ORM documentation for how to use those types.

Comment: I support @JonSeigel 's comment. And you can give length of string using attributes in Ormlite.

Comment: I agree with @JonSeigel, unless you have to support SQL 2000. In that case you may be forced to struggle with the likes of `text`, `ntext` and `image`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert your `Body` type to `byte[]` from `string` for ServiceStack.OrmLite to use the `varchar(max)` column type. Something like the below:

```
public byte[] Body { get; set; }
```

The reason for this lies within the ServiceStack.OrmLite code.

In the file [ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.cs#L236), under the method `InitColumnTypeMap()` is:

```
DbTypeMap.Set<byte[]>(DbType.Binary, BlobColumnDefinition);
```

In the file [ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer/SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer/SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.cs#L27), under the method `SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider()` is:

```
base.BlobColumnDefinition = "VARBINARY(MAX)";
```

From this code, you can see that an internal mapping is taking place from the C# type to the internal ServiceStack.OrmLite type and then back out to the SqlServer type.

This question explains how to convert back and forth between strings and byte arrays, [How do I get a consistent byte representation of strings in C# without manually specifying an encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/472906/299327).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you ***really*** want `NTEXT`. If you want `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25729568/37055

Decorate your domain model with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute`

such as

```
[StringLengthAttribute(8001)]
public string Markdown { get;set; }
```

or

```
[StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
public string Markdown { get;set; }
```

using any length greater than 8000 to exceed to maximum length of Sql Server `varchar`/`nvarchar` column types.

Use a custom dialect provider the understands the `NTEXT` declaration.

```
public class NTextSqlProvider : SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider
{
  public new static readonly NTextSqlProvider Instance = new NTextSqlProvider();

  public override string GetColumnDefinition(string fieldName, Type fieldType, 
            bool isPrimaryKey, bool autoIncrement, bool isNullable, 
            int? fieldLength, int? scale, string defaultValue)
  {
     var fieldDefinition = base.GetColumnDefinition(fieldName, fieldType,
                                    isPrimaryKey, autoIncrement, isNullable, 
                                    fieldLength, scale, defaultValue);

     if (fieldType == typeof (string) && fieldLength > 8000)
     {
       var orig = string.Format(StringLengthColumnDefinitionFormat, fieldLength);

       fieldDefinition = fieldDefinition.Replace(orig, "NTEXT");
     }

     return fieldDefinition;
  }
}
```

Use the provider when you construct the database factory

```
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(conStr, NTextSqlProvider.Instance);
```