# Read a String like a StreamReader

Tags: c#, streamreader

First of all: Sorry for my bad English!

I know the title isn't the best English, but I don't really know how to format this question...
What I'm trying to do is reading an HTML source line by line so when it sees a given word (like http://) it copies the entire sentence so I can strip the rest an only keep the URL.

This is what I've tried:

```
using (var source = new StreamReader(TempFile))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = source.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("http://"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly if I want to read it from an external file but it doesn't work when I want to read an string or stringbuilder, how do you read those line by line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `new StringReader(theString)` to do that with a `string`, but I question your overall strategy. That would be better done with a tool like HTML Agility Pack.

For example, here is HTML Agility Pack extracting all hyperlinks:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(theString);
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
{
   HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
   Console.WriteLine(att.Value);
}
```

Comment: I agree. Also make sure to use ScrapySharp as well with HtmlAgilityPack. It let's you use familiar jQuery syntax to select elements. Literally doubles your productivity. http://www.romcyber.com/post/2012/01/27/ScrapySharp-in-english-%29.aspx

Comment: But that's another dependency... Not saying it's necessarily bad, just a thing to consider.

Comment: @vines: A trivial issue. The library is very small.

Comment: @vines compared to parsing html **properly**, it is a trivial thing

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't think this code is going to work, mainly because the link is somewhere in a javascript :(.

Answer (score 0):

Well a string is just a string, it doesn't have any lines.

You can use something like `String.Split` to separate on the `\r` symbol.

MSDN: [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
string words = "This is a list of words, with: a bit of punctuation" +
                       "\rand a newline character.";

string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {'\r' });

foreach (string s in split) {
    if (s.Trim() != "")       
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use a [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx).

Another option is to create a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) from the string via converting the string to a byte array first, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380166/396583

Answer (score 0):

I think you can tokenize the input and check each entry for the required content.

```
 string[] info = myStringBuilder.toString().split[' '];
 foreach(var item in info) {
 if(item.Contains('http://') {
    //work with it
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a memory stream to read from.