# Error when trying to convert a byte array to string.....c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

This is my code:

```
byte[] base64String = //this is being set properly
var base64CharArray = new char[base64String.Length];
Convert.ToBase64CharArray(base64String,
                          0,
                          base64String.Length,
                          base64CharArray,
                          0);
var Base64String = new string(base64CharArray);
```

When i run this, I get the following error when calling `Convert.ToBase64CharArray`:

> Either offset did not refer to a position in the string, or there is an insufficient      length of destination character array. Parameter name: offsetOut

How do i fix this, so i can convert my byte array to a string, or is there a better way to convert a byte array to a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need the char array? Just convert your `byte[]` [directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) to a Base64 `string`:

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(myByteArray);
```

Comment: Yes!. This is what i was looking for. Thank you. I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes

Answer (score 1):

base64 encoding needs 4 characters to encode 3 bytes of input. you have to enlarge your output array.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way you can convert byte array to string

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str) 
{ 
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)]; 
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
    return bytes; 
} 

static string GetString(byte[] bytes) 
{ 
    char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)]; 
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length); 
    return new string(chars); 
}
```

you don't really need to worry about encoding.

more details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple form of doing it

```
string System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(YourbyteArray)
```