# Cast byte string to human-readble old-fashion string

Tags: c#, .net

Good morning\evening everyone!

i have a string in a format like `"0x0SD30SV8GN48N84GN"` wich represent a byte array... how can i turn that on a actual `byte[]`?

the actual string is quite longer.

It represents a string in UTF-8 format that im trying to convert to `UTF-32`...

what i want is to turn that to a human readble string... is that possible?

PS: The scenario is: my colleague stored a string in a varbinary column... executed a "Select myVarBinaryColumn FROM mytable" and sent me the result as txt... i need to convert to a human readble string...

PS2: the string can be understand as the result of the following operation: Cast('Hello World' as varbinary(max))

Comment: How does this string represent a byte array? And what do you mean by represents a string in UTF-8 format? Strings always use UTF-16 in .net. Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: @CodesInChaos did you notice that the string starts with "0x" that is a international notation to indicate a hexadecimal number. If you have a MSSQL database engine close by that the following "Cast('Hello World' as varBinary(Max))"

Comment: I noticed The `0x`, but I also noticed plenty of non hex characters. So I wrote off the `0x` as coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string byteStr = input.Substring(2);
byte[] bytes = new byte [ byteStr.Length / 2 ];
for ( int i = 0, j = 0 ; i < byteStr.Length ; i += 2 , j++ )
{
     bytes [ j ] = byte.Parse ( byteStr.Substring ( i , 2 ) , NumberStyles.HexNumber );
}
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString ( bytes );
byte[] UTF32Bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes ( str );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
byte[] array = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(somestring);
```

Comment: I have updated my answer after noticing that OP wants to convert to UTF32

Comment: While I'm still not sure it's what the OP wants, it's no longer clearly the wrong thing(ASCII certainly wasn't correct). So I've removed the download. If it's not what the OP wants, it's his own fault for asking an unclear question.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I agree with you, I noticed your comment to OP and expected clearity

Answer (score 1):

```
 string yourstring ="0x0SD30SV8GN48N84GN";
 byte[] array = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(yourstring);
```

check out [this link.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-string-byte-array)
also, there's another very similar question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp)