# Base64 String posting to URL

Tags: c#, .net

I have string of text that needs to be cnoverted to base64 before being posted to a url.
Here is my code

```
  HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
      byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strCXML);
       string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(postDataBytes);
       req.Method = "POST";
       req.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
       req.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
       Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
       requestStream.Write(returnValue,0, postDataBytes.Length);
```

Problem is i get error on the last line System.IO.Stream.Write(byte[],int,int)
returnValue is base64 string cant be used as byte[] needed in stream.writer
Any idea how to take that that base64 string called returnvalue and put it to a url
thanks

Comment: You need to convert the string to a byte[]. This post shows how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Stream as your requestStream.  Stream.Write takes a byte array, not a Base64 string.

I think you are doing it in the wrong order.  I would convert strCXML to a Base64 String first then encode it into a byte array to write to the request stream.

Answer (score 4):

You should convert your base64 string into byte array by Encoding.GetBytes

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strCXML);
string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(postDataBytes);

postDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(returnValue);

req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
```

Comment: +1 for good answer. You forgot to change argument in Write call, so I did that for you. Also removed an unnecessary duplicated line that exists in the source as well.

Comment: You should merk it as an ansver