# C# Encoding Conversion

Tags: c#, encoding

I have an encrypt routine in c++, I translate this to C#:

**example:**

```
public void main()
{
    string myPwd = "ÖFÖæ6";
    string pwdCoded = XEncrypt.EncryptData_Patch_x_Net(myPwd);
    //Result OK: ÖFÖæ–6
}

public static string EncryptData_Patch_x_Net(string Data)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[Data.Length];

    for (int n = 0; n < Data.Length; n++)
    {
        bytes[n] = (byte)Data[n];
    }

    System.Text.Encoding MyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
    String MyResult = MyEncoding.GetString(bytes);
    return MyResult;
}
```

I need to make the inverse routine that made it convert from:

**`ÖFÖæ–6`** to **`ÖFÖæ6`** (notice there's a dash in the left string)

I did this last function, but erroneously performs the encoding

```
public static string DecryptData_Patch_x_Net(string Data)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[Data.Length];

    for (int n = 0; n < Data.Length; n++)
    {
        bytes[n] = (byte)Data[n];
    }

    System.Text.Encoding MyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
    String MyResult = MyEncoding.GetString(bytes);
    return MyResult;
}
```

Comment: encryption != encoding, decryption != decoding. Anyway, all strings in .Net are unicode.

Comment: I ran your code, and didn't get your expected result ÖFÖæ–6. My default encoding is 1252, as I imagine yours is too.

Comment: You can use the `System.Text.Encoding` namespace to control how `string`s are converted to and from `byte[]`s and `Stream`s but, all strings are unicode.

Comment: @Jonathan the control character in ISO-8859-1 that corresponds to the `–` in Windows-1252, didn't make it to the question. You should try it with `pwd = "ÖFÖæ\u00966"`;

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Discrepencies of coverage between the default code page and Windows-1252 will effect your ability to round trip.

Answer (score 5):

This is not encryption and you are seriously complicating what it actually is.

```
Encoding iso88591 = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
Encoding w1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

//
string pwd = "ÖFÖæ\u00966"; //The SPA control character will not survice a Stackoverflow post
                            //So I use \u0096 to represent it

string result = w1252.GetString(iso88591.GetBytes(pwd)); //"ÖFÖæ–6"

string original = iso88591.GetString(w1252.GetBytes(result)); //"ÖFÖæ6" with the hidden control character before 6

Console.WriteLine(result == "ÖFÖæ–6"); //True
Console.WriteLine(original == "ÖFÖæ\u00966"); //True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your misnamed `...Encrypt...` function makes a fundamental error. You take a `string`, which treat as a `char[]` (thats fine), then explicitly cast each `char` to a `byte`. That is a narrowing conversion. You'll lose any of the high bits and the ability to round trip more unusual `char`s. If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp) it should help to understand.

You could use this function to get the bytes without loss of information,

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

The byte array will round trip on systems that share endianess.

---

As Esailija states, becuase its simple and it will explicitly return little endian results, you're better off calling

```
byte[] Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(string)
```

[To achieve the same.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx)

Comment: He doesn't lose high bits, but unicode code points that are above 255 (such as `–`, but not `Ö` or `æ` for example). What your function does is a convoluted way of calling `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)`, that is, encode a string as UTF-16LE.

Comment: @Esailija, I agree with you comment. The higher code points are stored in the high bits. If the `chars` are stored with the right Endianess this code is equivalent to `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)`.

Comment: Ah yes, the internal encoding varies depending on machine. In that case `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str) : Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(str)` can be used. But his "encryption" doesn't want UTF-16 at all is my point.

Comment: @Esailija I'm not sure what the OP wants to be honest.