# Original file bytes from StreamReader, magic number detection

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, .net-4.0, magic-numbers

I'm trying to differentiate between "text files" and "binary" files, as I would effectively like to ignore files with "unreadable" contents.

I have a file that I believe is a GZIP archive.  I'm tring to ignore this kind of file by detecting the magic numbers / file signature.  If I open the file with the Hex editor plugin in Notepad++ I can see the first three hex codes are `1f 8b 08`.

However if I read the file using a `StreamReader`, I'm not sure how to get to the original bytes..

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\file"))
{
    char[] buffer = new char[10];
    streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, 10);
    var s = new String(buffer);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[6];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(s.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, 6);
    var hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);

    var otherhex = BitConverter.ToString(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s.ToCharArray()));
}
```

At the end of the using statement I have the following variable values:

```
hex: "1F-00-FD-FF-08-00"
otherhex: "1F-EF-BF-BD-08-00-EF-BF-BD-EF-BF-BD-0A-51-02-03"
```

Neither of which start with the hex values shown in Notepad++.

Is it possible to get the original bytes from the result of reading a file via `StreamReader`?

Comment: just test the bytes in the bytes array, you don't need all that string stuff

Comment: The problem is (despite the example above) I actually start with a string (which I know was produced by a StreamReader) and I was hoping not to have to change how the string was supplied.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10380166/62072) seems to indicate that it's possible to get the original bytes from a string.. What am I missing?

Comment: 1F that you see in your hex reader is 31 converted to 49(x31) ('1') and 70(x46) 'F' Char(x1f) is in ascii the the US char (unit separator) a non printable like esc or bell. so if you are looking for the bytes after effectively converting the to chars you'ev got to look for Char(x1f) Char(8B) char(8)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code tries to change a binary buffer into a string. Strings are Unicode in NET so two bytes are required. The resulting is a bit unpredictable as you can see.

Just use a BinaryReader and its [ReadBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx) method

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fs, new ASCIIEncoding()))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        buffer = reader.ReadBytes(10);
        if(buffer[0] == 31 && buffer[1] == 139 && buffer[2] == 8)
            // you have a signature match....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Usage (for a pdf file):

```
Assert.AreEqual("25504446", GetMagicNumbers(filePath, 4));
```

Method GetMagicNumbers:

```
private static string GetMagicNumbers(string filepath, int bytesCount)
{
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

    byte[] buffer;
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fs))
        buffer = reader.ReadBytes(bytesCount);

    var hex = BitConverter.ToString(buffer);
    return hex.Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `StreamReader` is made to read text, not binary. Use the `Stream` directly to read bytes. In your case `FileStream`.

To guess whether a file is text or binary you could read the first 4K into a `byte[]` and interpret that.

Btw, you tried to force chars into bytes. This is invalid by principle. I suggest you familiarize yourself with what an `Encoding` is: it is the *only* way to convert between chars and bytes in a semantically correct way.