# .Net BlockCopy and DB2 Character Conversion using CodePage

Tags: c#, .net

I understand that collation can be set differently in different tables in a database. Collation is understood from [What does character set and collation mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly)

There is a query that performs `CAST` from a char results as shown below. There are no tables involved.  I guess, the encoding applied will be based on the collation in database level. Is this assumption correct?

```
SELECT  CAST ( SSS.id_encrypt ('E','0000000{0}') AS CHAR(100) FOR BIT DATA)  
AS ENCRYPT_ID FROM FFGLOBAL.ONE_ROW FETCH  FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

**QUESTION**

In the question [Get Byte[] from Db2 without Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153100/get-byte-from-db2-without-encoding)  answer given by @AlexFilipovici [.Net `BlockCopy` ] provides a different result when compared to `CAST` result. Why is it so if there is no `codepage` associated?

Based on  [National language support - Character conversion](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0004123.htm)

> Bit data (columns defined as FOR BIT DATA, or BLOBs, or binary strings) is not associated with any character set.

**REFERENCE**

1. [Get Byte[] from Db2 without Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153100/get-byte-from-db2-without-encoding)
2. [Default code page for new databases is Unicode](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc%2Fdoc%2Fi0052421.html)
3. [National language support - Character conversion](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0004123.htm)

Comment: Don't ask one question like this covering two different RDBMSs as the answers will likely be completely different. They are two separate questions. (Edit actually I see you have actually asked **four** questions!)

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks. I have updated the question to make it DB2 specific

Comment: I think you have too many questions being asked here. Also, our DBA site may be a better place for this question, if you'd like it migrated.

Comment: @Kev To answer this question .Net related knowledge is needed (.Net BlockCopy). Hence it is not good to move to DBA site.

Answer (score 1):

To find out the collation at database level in SQL Server, try this:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('databasename', 'Collation');
```

More: [DATABASEPROPERTYEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. However that's only 1/3rd of the question.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it DB2 specific based on comments from other users.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

#1: Specifying `FOR BIT DATA` on a character-based data type (in DB2) means that DB2 stores / returns the raw data back with no codepage associated (i.e. it's just a string of bytes and will not go through any codepage conversion between client and server).

#2: In DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows, you can determine the database's collation by querying `SYSIBMADM.DBCFG`

```
 select name,value
  from sysibmadm.dbcfg
 where name in ('codepage','codeset');
```

#3: Per @Iswanto San:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('databasename', 'Collation');
```

Comment: In the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153100/get-byte-from-db2-without-encoding answer given by @AlexFilipovici provides a different result when compared to CAST resut. Why is it so if there is `no codepage associated` ?

Comment: If there is a codepage associated then the DB2 server will perform codepage conversion between the database's codepage (i.e. how data is stored in the database) and the client application's codepage.  The `GetBytes()` function in the solution you point out is working with data that's already been modified between client/server.

Comment: Why do this question and above comment not answer your question?