# Convert Image to Byte array and vice versa

Tags: c#

This may be an existing question but the answers I got is not exactly what I'm looking for.

In C# Winforms, I want to convert the image (not the path) from the picturebox and convert it into  Byte array and display that  Byte array in label.

Currently, this is what I have.

```
Byte[] result = (Byte[]) new ImageConverter().ConvertTo(pbOrigImage.Image, typeof(Byte[]));
```

Then, after displaying the  Byte array in label, I want to convert it from  Byte array to image. I currently don't have codes when it comes to image to  Byte array conversion. But is this possible?

Comment: What do you think binary is? It seems to differ from what I think binary is

Comment: Do you want to display the contents of your byte array? If so, in which format? Should it be editable and you want to convert it back from string to Image?

Comment: @CaiusJard Hi. i updated my question. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @JBartlau Yes. I want to display the all the contents of my image byte array. Any format will do as long as it can be converted again into image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following methods for conversion from `byte[]` to `Image`,

```
public byte[] ConvertImageToBytes(Image img)
    {
        byte[] arr;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            arr = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public Image ConvertBytesToImage(byte[] arr)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arr))
        {
            return Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
```

To convert`byte[]` to a `string` or vice-versa, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306104/c-sharp-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: You shouldn't dispose the stream in `ConvertBytesToImage` which will corrupt the bitmap. Try: `public Image ConvertBytesToImage(byte[] arr) => new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(arr)));` .....

Comment: JPEG? I thought this way supposed to be a round trip...