# How to get UTF-16 byte array?

Tags: c#, encoding

I have an `UTF-8` string and I need to get the byte array of `UTF-16` encoding, so how can I convert my string to `UTF-16` byte array?

**Update:**
I mean we have `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` or even `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` function to get byte array of strings, what about `UTF-16`? We don't have any `Encoding.UTF16.GetBytes()` so how can I get the byte array?

Comment: you probably either have a string or an UTF-8 byte array. String is a type that contains characters, regardless of encoding, as encoding is only for byte array representation

Comment: also, what have you tried, and please post your code

Comment: What do you mean by "I have an UTF-8 string" to start with? If you have an instance of System.String, it will be UTF-16 in memory already.

Comment: A string in C# is always `UTF-16`, I believe there is no way to _convert_ it. What is your `UTF-8` string looks like?

Comment: @njzk2: Not quite: strings are sequences of UTF-16 code units. That's important in the case of non-BMP characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp

"Internally, the .NET framework uses UTF16 to represent strings, so if you simply want to get the exact bytes that .NET uses, use System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes". Regardless, that answer contains the code to get the UTF-16 representation.

Comment: @JonSkeet : the internal array that backs the string is indeed in utf16, but the string itself doesn't have a notion of encoding. The encoding will be relevant only when converting to/from a byte array

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani: from the Encoding MSDN: `Unicode Gets an encoding for the UTF-16 format using the little endian byte order.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For little-endian UTF-16, use [`Encoding.Unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx).

For big-endian UTF-16, use [`Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.bigendianunicode.aspx).

Alternatively, construct an explicit instance of [`UnicodeEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.aspx) which allows you to specify the endianness, whether or not to include byte-order marks, and whether to throw an exception on invalid data.

Answer (score 12):

> I have an UTF-8 string and ...

No you don't. That's not possible. You may have a sequence (array or stream) of `byte`s that hold UTF-8 encoded text. But not a `string`.

A .net `string` always contains Unicode (or more precisely, UTF-16).

> ..., so how can I convert my string to UTF-16 byte array?

```
string myText = ...;  // some string, maybe from an UTF8 file or any other source
byte[] utf16Data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myText);
```

The library defines the range **UTF7**, **UTF8**, **Unicode**, **UTF32**. Unicode *is* UTF16 in the context of the .NET framework.

Comment: Unicode is UTF-16 ... yes, in the dialect of .NET. For the rest of the world, Unicode is an enumeration of characters (codepoints), and UTF-16 is one implementation of this enumeration on at least 2 bytes