# How do I write a string to the resources of a file

Tags: vb.net, file, resources

How would I write a string resource to a file using Visual Basic .NET (2010)?

Here's a method to write a byte-array to resources, but that's not what I want. I want to write a string resource.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Module ResourceWriter
Private Function ToPtr(ByVal data As Object) As IntPtr
    Dim h As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    Dim ptr As IntPtr
    Try
        ptr = h.AddrOfPinnedObject()
    Finally
        h.Free()
    End Try
    Return ptr

End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Function UpdateResource(ByVal hUpdate As IntPtr, ByVal lpType As String, ByVal lpName As String, ByVal wLanguage As UShort, ByVal lpData As IntPtr, ByVal cbData As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Function BeginUpdateResource(ByVal pFileName As String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bDeleteExistingResources As Boolean) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Function EndUpdateResource(ByVal hUpdate As IntPtr, ByVal fDiscard As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function

Public Function WriteResource(ByVal filename As String, ByVal bytes As Byte()) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim handle As IntPtr = BeginUpdateResource(filename, False)
        Dim file1 As Byte() = bytes
        Dim fileptr As IntPtr = ToPtr(file1)
        Dim res As Boolean = UpdateResource(handle, "RT_RCDATA", "0", 0, fileptr, Convert.ToUInt32(file1.Length))
        EndUpdateResource(handle, False)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True

End Function
End Module
```

Comment: what the nature of the file you are trying to write to?  DLL, Managed EXE, Win32 EXE etc?

Comment: Just a native EXE file.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string into a byte array easily by doing this:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Str)
```

And to conver back:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString
```

Or, you can get into some deep conversation about encodeing over here: [net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp)