# How to insert DateTime object using Odbc?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datetime, odbc

Simple MySQL table containing a single column of type `timestamp`.

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (?)", DbConnection);
command.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.Timestamp).Value = DateTime.Now;
OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

> InvalidCastException: Could not convert parameter from DateTime to
>   Byte[]

Error has been translated, but you get the point. How do I insert it correctly?

FYI: I also tried to convert the formatted DateTime string (`.ToString(""yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"")`) to a byte array using the function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380166/941764). It inserts fine but it results is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ObdcType.DateTime instead of OdbcType.Timestamp.

More details on:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx