# Force a memory level cast

Tags: c#, memory, casting, low-level

Iirc from C, you can have a statement along these lines:

```
char* str = "1234";
int nonStr = *((int*)str);
```

(I intentionally made the string 4 characters so in the average scenario it will have the same number of bytes as the integer.)  This will dereference the memory where `str` is stored and give you the value if it was an integer (`522207554` if I did the conversion right).

Is there any way to do the same thing in C#?  I know this is a low level memory operation which is generally blissfully hidden from the C# programmer, I am only doing this for a teaching exercise.

Comment: A 'teaching' exercise! Surely we'd want to encourage good habits and not to abuse pointers like this - especially in C#. If you want to teach pointer abuse, at least do it in a context that's appropriate - C/C++ in a low level/OS environment. Not C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET String to byte Array C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp)

Comment: @Skizz the whole point of abusing them is to "point" out that they can be abused, even accidentally.  I want to explain what's going on in memory behind the scenes so the students will understand why they get an `InvalidCastException`!  I don't intend to teach them to ever write "real" programs this way.

Comment: There are `IntPtr` objects in .NET and you can do pointer manipulation inside `unsafe` blocks. What pointer are you trying to manipulate to begin with? Unless it's an IntPtr, something marshaled or a pointer created inside an unsafe block, I don't think there's anything you can do with it as far as low level memory manipulation goes.

Comment: That's my point. Use C as the tool to explain how memory works, and then talk about how C# abstracts the memory interface into more strictly controlled access that leads to InvalidCast. Teaching them how to abuse pointers in C# and they'll resort to doing it when they hit a problem rather than refactoring and improving the design. It's kinda like using `goto` in C++, it just leads to this: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: C code like that formally invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @just.another.programmer: `str` points to a statically-allocated array of `char`s, and the strict aliasing rule says (approximately) that you can't access an object of one type through a pointer to a different type (with a few exceptions that this does not fall into). This permits certain optimizations that are sometimes desirable. The code in your question could have its undefined behavior removed by using `memcpy(&nonStr, str, sizeof(nonStr))`. (This invokes one of the allowable exceptions—non-`char` things can be used as `char`, but not vice-versa.) More information is available elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using unsafe context and `fixed`statement:

```
static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "1234";
    fixed(char* strPtr = str)
    {
        int* nonStr = (int*)strPtr;
        Console.WriteLine(*nonStr);
    }
}
```

prints

```
3276849
```

Comment: `char` in C# is a two-byte struct (UTF-16 encoding), so you'd want **2** characters in a string. You can see that here: 3276849 in hex is 0x00320031 ("34" weren't copied).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `unsafe` functionality of C#.

Here's [one reference](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/csharp/9781449379629/advanced-csharp/unsafe_code_and_pointers). A general search for "C# unsafe pointer dereference" turns up many results.

Answer (score 0):

Would a union simulation be sufficient for this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acxa5b99.aspx