# Get first 30 bytes from string c#

Tags: c#, string, byte

How to get first 30 bytes from string?

Eg: `string phone = "My name is 绳図轉丰 blah blah";` then

Function returned "My name" (30 bytes)
Thanks for help.

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
byte[] bytes;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
string orig = "喂 Hello 谢谢 Thank You";
bf.Serialize(ms, orig);
ms.Seek(0, 0);
bytes = ms.ToArray();
MessageBox.Show("Original bytes Length: " + bytes.Length.ToString());
MessageBox.Show("Original string Length: " + orig.Length.ToString());
```

Comment: Strings don't have "bytes" (they are sequences of characters), unless you convert them to a `byte[]` - e.g. [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55(v=vs.110).aspx) - under a *specific* encoding. (In this case, "My name" will only be close-ish to 30 bytes under UTF32.)

Comment: Come on, read some docs.....

Comment: Why not type your question into a search engine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET String to byte Array C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c-sharp)

Comment: I read this answer but i not get total bytes, i wanna only 30 bytes split from string sorry for my bad English

Comment: @user2989391 To get the first N-bytes, with LINQ: `byte[] upToFirst30Bytes = bytes.Take(30).ToArray();` (however, the BinaryFormatter use seems suspect.)

Answer (score 5):

As others said, string itself does not have byte representation which depends on encoding used. You can try this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Your string with some interesting data").Take(30);
```

But you have to remember that depending on selected encoding, values returned by GetBytes method may differ.

Comment: With the added code, it seems like the `Take(30)` is relevant (so +1). The OP might want to turn it back to an array, however: `bytes = bytes.Take(30).ToArray()`.

Comment: i like the use of Take

Comment: How to using this code?

Comment: `'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type 'byte[]' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Chad you're probably missing using System.Linq;