# Alternative to std::string in C#

Tags: c#, c++, string, type-conversion

I have been trying to find a replacement string function that would allow me to use std::string like behaviour in C#. I just need it for some code I ported across from C++ to C# that had std::strings in them. I've read about converting the strings to byte array and then working it out from there although I am unable to do so. Any possible suggestion of doing this with an example code? Please note the below code was written in C++ using std::strings instead of C# Unicode string.

***C++ Code***

```
std::string DeMangleCode(const std::string& argMangledCode) const
{
   std::string unencrypted;
   for (uint32_t temp = 0; temp < argMangledCode.size(); temp++)
   {
      unencrypted += argMangledCode[temp] ^ (434 + temp) % 255;
   }
   return unencrypted;
}
```

Mangled Input: ‚‡…ƒ

Output: 1305

Comment: But that's not C++ code.

Comment: Yup it isnt, its just an effort to show what I actually mean code-wise. As I mentioned, just replace the strings to std::string to get the C++ version of the code.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the [`Chars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) method.

Comment: My C/C++ is very rusty, but IIRC `std::string` talks `char`, and `char` is single-byte. In that case, you should be using `byte[]`, not `string`

Comment: Yup, you are right Marc. That's what I have been reading through on forums as well. Any possible answers?

Comment: Seen this one, but I'm not sure how I can convert my code to suit this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array

Comment: `std::string` does not have `^=` operator that takes a `char` (or any other argument type). I can't even guess what would that operator do. What would you like to happen in this code? Give us example input and example output.

Comment: Its basically decrypting the code. Input possibly is lets say: '‚‡…ƒ' and output would be 1305. (just an example - not the exact code I have stated above).

Comment: We need exact code, and only then would we know what is exact translation to C#.

Comment: Yup just updated it. Added exact C++ code.

Comment: Strings in C# are Unicode (UTF-16) in general, so with modulo 255 information would be lost. If it is guaranteed that no character would go above ASCII range then you could use `StringBuilder` for `unencrypted` variable, and return `unencrypted.ToString()`.

Comment: -1: It is still unclear what exactly is missing from `string` for you - C# `string` is already indexable, you can add characters to existing string... (indeed @Dialecticus suggestion about `StringBuilder` is proper approach, but direct translation of above code does not require it)

Comment: The name of this function is "DeMangleCode". Give us one mangled input, and expected demangled output.

Comment: I actually did as a comment.. Updating my question with that change.

Comment: @TheNewbie I updated my answer. It should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will return "1305" for input "‚‡…ƒ". The trick was to figure out which code page was used when the string was mangled. It was code page 1252.

```
static public string DeMangleCode(string argMangledCode)
{
    Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
    byte[] argMangledCodeBytes = enc.GetBytes(argMangledCode);
    List<byte> unencrypted = new List<byte>();
    for (int temp = 0; temp < argMangledCodeBytes.Length; temp++)
    {
        unencrypted.Add((byte)(argMangledCodeBytes[temp] ^ (434 + temp) % 255));
    }
    return enc.GetString(unencrypted.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I dint know about this code page although I was trying it myself just sometime back. Thanks for updating the answer.