# C# Converting a String to Bytes

Tags: c#, string, int, byte

I have a program that uses encryption text strings, I basically just want to write a simple program that will print out all of the decrypted text for me.

For example: Say that the letter "A" = the byte "2C"; I would want to type the letter A in to the program and have it print out "2C" for me.

Does anybody know an easy way to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Note, any 'encryption' that consists of mapping letters like "A" = "2C" is *terrible* encryption.

Comment: probably need to do your homework yourself :)

Comment: I agree, sadly I did not create the encryption myself.

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary<char, byte>` to map one to the other (assuming that there isn't a simple function that would work), but note that you don't have enough space to account for all possible Unicode characters.  Consider encoding the string as UTF-8 and then performing the encryption on the resulting byte array.

Comment: @cdhowie's suggestion of just creating a dictionary is a perfectly good solution as long as you're dealing with a fairly small set of characters (e.g. ASCII).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a String to byte Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 1):

By `2C` I think you mean the hex representation of the letter `A`?

That would be something like `String.Format("{0:X}", Convert.ToInt32('A'));`

**Update after clarification from OP**

You either need to predefine your entire supported character set like this.

```
    static Dictionary<char, int> cyper = new Dictionary<char, int>
{
{'A', 44},
{'B', 45},
{'C', 46},
{'D', 47},
{'E', 48},
{'F', 49},
// .. etc
};
```

// ...

```
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:X}", cyper['A'])); // will print 2C
```

But that doesn't seem like a very good encryption if everything is just off by a few values.

Another approach would be to apply an encoding scheme. A runtime mathematical evaluation on the input that will evaluate to 2C (encrypt) and be able to take 2C and evaluate to A (decrypt).

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, yes. Thank you.

Comment: Ah yes good call, forgot a step, you gotta convert it to the underlying int first.

Comment: Now a format exception. Try this: `String.Format("{0:X}", (int)'A');`

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that.

Comment: You corrected the main issue, but you still have the same problem as the other answer. The hex value of the ASCII / Unicode `A` is `41`, not `2C`.

Comment: What is the encoding being used? That's what will drive the underlying value.

Comment: According to the question, it's not an encoding but some kind of '*encryption*'.

Comment: Gotcha, well then there's not enough information to provide an answer.

Comment: The program encrypts all text. So instead of the letter "A" being 0x41 within the program, the letter "A" is 0x2C. If I want to change the text, I have to use that format. All I am trying to do is create a program that I can input all of the letters into with their proper hex representation (within the scope of this project) so that when I type the letter it prints the hex.

You've all encountered exactly what I have; the value of A is 0x41 by default. I need a way to redefine that value for each letter of the alphabet so that it would print A = 0x2C instead of A = 0x41, etc.

Comment: @user3809661 I'll amend my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try like this:

```
byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (yourString);
```

Comment: With this method, `"A"` → `[0x41]`. If OP expects a different mapping, e.g. `"A"` → `[0x2C]`, this won't work.

Comment: @p.s.w.g:- Hmm..makes a sense.  But I thought this is the correct way to proceed with when you want to **convert** a string to byte otherwise it would be just a format change like `String.Format("{0:X}", (int)'A');` is  not the conversion in the real sense. Stumped :(

Comment: Minus 41 (I think) from the result to get the numerically-based index (1 - 52) if it's UNICODE