# C# - how to move bytes from StringBuilder to a byte array

Tags: c#

A dll for USB communications reads data and puts it into a StringBuilder instance, bRx.
How can the bytes of data in bRx be moved to a byte buffer to ultimately be written to a file?

Comment: if you're written them to a file, why do you need them as byte buffer ? you can just use `File.WriteAllText`

Comment: Which bytes? Why are they in a StringBuilder in the first place? Do you want a byte representation of _text_ in the StringBuilder? Or does the text in the StringBuilder represent binary data in some numeric format (e.g. hexadecimal)? You really need to post a less-vague question. Give some example code of what you're dealing with, along with some sample data.

Answer (score 2):

It may vary depending on how the string is encoded / what is stored in it

But try this:

```
byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
```

or

```
byte[] b = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
```

See the SO thread regarding String which should apply to StringBuilder:

[How do I get a consistent byte representation of strings in C# without manually specifying an encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: I've tried your 1st suggestion. The first byte in SB is 0xff. The problem is that it gets translated to two bytes in the byte buffer, 0xC3 followed by 0xBF.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a separator needed if you are adding using `Append(byte value)`. Microsoft has an example there with a `" "` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86yy043k(v=vs.110).aspx

I've prepared an example that fits more to your needs I think:

```cs
const char separator = ';';
byte[] inputBytes = { 255, 16, 1 };

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte b in inputBytes)
    sb.Append(b).Append(separator);

// remove a separator in a tail
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);


var byteArrayActual = sb.ToString()
        .Split(separator)
        .Select(x => byte.Parse(x))
        .ToArray();

Debug.Assert(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(inputBytes, byteArrayActual));
```

After the above code executed there is the same array (as initial) that is ready to be saved to a file: `Byte[] (3 items) 255 16 1`.