# how to take two words from a string and then add a -

Tags: c#, split, byte

Morning guys 
So I have this sanario
a user enters text into a textbox 
the text is something in the following format

```
0123456789ABCDEF
```

I want to be able to split the Text given by the user as

```
01-23-45-67-89-AB-CD-EF
```

is this possible ?

And then if possible how can I convert this string to byte ?

All done in c#

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean, byte?  You are just showing the same string with embedded dashes.

Comment: Im using this as a type of lock key I ment the original string how can I convert the string as it is there to byte ?     Like 01 as byte 0x01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string output = "0123456789ABCDEF";
int i = 2;

while (i < output.Length) {
    output = output.Insert(i, "-");
    i += 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do it this way for a byte array?

```
string output = "0123456789ABCDEF";
int i = 2;

while (i < output.Length) {
    output = output.Insert(i, ",");
    i += 3;
}

byte[] array = {output};
```

Comment: No it will give that cannot implicitly convert strinf to byte but thanks I tried that yesterday

Answer (score 0):

This may have been answered here: [Converting String to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array-without-using-an-encoding-byte-by-byte)

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my preferred way:

```
var result = String.Join("-", text.Buffer(2).Select(x => new string(x.ToArray())));
```

You just need to get the Interactive Framework (NuGet `Ix-Main`) from Microsoft's Reactive Framework team.