# Converitng String to Byte in C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to convert   string  to Byte.
The value of the string was updated by reading XML

```
  string MyValue= Node.Attributes["Value"].Value.ToUpper().ToString(); 
  MyValue = "NETWORK";
  MyObject.MyValue= Convert.ToByte(MyValue);

  Even tried with using Encoding Option
```

But I was getting error as "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: 7 char string will never be fit into one byte

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `Convert.ToByte` works. It doesn't do encoding stuff at all.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Not clear what you want to do. Not clear what `MyObject` is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a string to byte-array without using an encoding (byte-by-byte)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array-without-using-an-encoding-byte-by-byte)

Answer (score 1):

The ToByte conversion will only convert a string representation of a number into bytes, eg this will work:

```
var testString = "1";

var result = Convert.ToByte(testString);
```

but this will not

```
var testString = "One";

var result = Convert.ToByte(testString);
```

Try something like this

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("NETWORK");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the encodings in `System.Text` such as ASCII:

```
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Convert("my string");
```