# How to convert video file name to byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am trying to convert my video file name that i have extracted from a folder to a byte array. My file name goes "video.mp4"

I have tried using this set of codes

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

but it does not work. Anyone?

Comment: What do you mean by "but it does not work"?. Be specific

Comment: If i guess right, you are passing the filename, not the path to the file.
But your question is confuse. Do you want to convert the file to a bytes array, or the name of the file (just the string) ?

Comment: @Nalaka we [don't add "thanks" to posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9107510). I see in your history you've been doing that to quite some posts. Please stop that.

Comment: @heyhihello please provide more info about why your code is not working

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to get the **name** or the **contents** into a byte array? Your code suggests you want to read the contents, however the question subjects the name.

Answer (score -1):

Another (maybe easier way) to convert a string to a byte array goes like this:

```
string filename = "video.mp4";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(filename);
```

To convert the byte array back to a string you can use:

```
string filename = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray);
```

For this to work you'll need to import the System.Text namespace.

Comment: Please read the comments. It is not clear what OP wants to do. If it is _"Get a string's characters in a byte array"_, then [that's a duplicate of this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array-without-using-an-encoding-byte-by-byte). Using the ASCII encoding is also not very failsafe; filenames can use Unicode characters as well.