# How do I convert a String to a BlobColumn in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

So I have a column in my `SSIS Script` Called `Data` which is of type `BlobColumn`

I want to assign this column to a `string` value.

I do the following:

```
Row.Data = "MyString";
```

but I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.BlobColumn

So how do I assign a `BlobColumn` to a `String` value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to byte-array without using an encoding (byte-by-byte)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array-without-using-an-encoding-byte-by-byte)

Comment: @TabAlleman Not a duplicate due to the extra step required here for the conversion. `Row.Data.AddBlobData(GetBytes("MyString"));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using the answer provided for [Converting a string to byte-array without using an encoding (byte-by-byte)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380166/2987066)

I did the following:

```
Row.Data.AddBlobData(GetBytes("MyString"));
```

*Where:*

```
byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you must decide in which encoding you are going to encode your string.
If you don't care, I recommend using:

- Little Endian UTF-16 for performance, since .NET strings are stored in that encoding

  ```
  System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("MyString");
  ```
- UTF-8 for storage

  ```
  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyString");
  ```

Consider reading more about encoding here: [Character Encoding in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding)

You should **NOT** use the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/how-do-i-get-a-consistent-byte-representation-of-strings-in-c-sharp-without-manu/10380166#10380166) .
Read the whole discussion there to understand why. The answer is for a very specific use case and a somewhat educational one.