# I want to store the label6.text value in byte[]cipherbytes..how to do that

Tags: c#

```
byte[]cipherbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(label6.Text);
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(cipherbytes);
```

Comment: How to store string value in byte?

Comment: sorry for that nextt time i'll carefull for that...

Answer (score 0):

To encode the string with a certain encoding, call `Encoding.<YourEncoding>.GetBytes()` on, not `GetString()`, this function is for returning a `string` given the `byte[]` representation of it. A possible Encoding could e.g. be ASCII or UTF8 encoding.

```
byte[] cipherbytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(label6.Text);
```

See also: [How do I get a consistent byte representation of strings in C# without manually specifying an encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/how-to-get-a-consistent-byte-representation-of-strings-in-c-sharp-without-manual), [Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.getbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks......i'll check it.....