# Convert.ToByte Could not find any recognizable digits

Tags: c#, .net

I need somehow convert "xxx" to byte but i got exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find any recognizable digits.

**Is it possible "xxx" value convert to byte?**

```
 byte tr  = (byte)(Convert.ToByte("xxx", 16) << 4);
```

Comment: byte[]  tr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxx") this work fine but i wondering how can i apply this shiftting 16) << 4);

Comment: Apply the shifting afterwards. You can't apply it in the convert.

Comment: what you are doing is converting xxx in 16 base to byte. we don't have xxx in 16 base.

Comment: oh okey than Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxx") how much base of byte here is?

Answer (score 1):

This line `(Convert.ToByte("xxx", 16) << 4)` will return `integer` which is not convertible into string when parsing to `byte` that's why it throws the [`System.FormatException`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/kb/942460).

But there is already a good example of how to convert the string into byte[].

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

[Source of Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380166/2575662)

Comment: than i got 120,0,120,0,120,0 but i with Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxx") i can get 120,120,120 so maybe is better Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxx")?

Comment: @IrmantasMedeišis It's up to you, the only benefit of my approach is you can still get the data and reconstruct the original string even if it contains an [invalid data](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt) because it's only looking at the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to convert "xxx" to a byte. It simply is not the representation of any byte.

Comment: byte[]  tr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxx"); but with this i got that x is 120

Comment: Which is a valid value

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change a string into a byte array :

```
 byte[] toBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xxx");
```