# Alternative to Buffer.MemoryCopy pre .NET 4.6

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to downgrade some .NET 4.6 code to .NET 4.5.

This is the code block I'm working with at the moment:

```
fixed (byte* destination = dataBytes)
{
    Buffer.MemoryCopy(data, destination, dataLength, dataLength);
}
```

`data` is `byte*` type so I don't know if `Buffer.BlockCopy()` is a reasonable replacement since it takes in Arrays.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that `Buffer.MemoryCopy` is .Net 4.6 or higher, `Buffer.BlockCopy` doesn't have the the desired overloads, and `Array.Copy` is out of the question also.

You could use the following however it will be slow

```
fixed (byte* pSource = source, pTarget = target)
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        pTarget[targetOffset + i] = pSource[sourceOffset + i];
```

If all else fails you can pinvoke memcpy from msvcrt.dll

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memcpy", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
public static extern IntPtr memcpy(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, UIntPtr count);
```

---

Also for .Net 4.5 you can use [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/)

[Unsafe.CopyBlock Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.copyblock?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1)

```
CopyBlock(Void*, Void*, UInt32)
```

> Copies a number of bytes specified as a long integer value from one
>   address in memory to another.

---

Lastly, you can use [`Marshal.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2) if you don't mind ending up in an array. However it doesn't have a pointer to pointer overload.

> Copies data from a managed array to an unmanaged memory pointer, or
>   from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed array.

Comment: Bare in mind, `memcpy` _"[is listed among the **banned** functions by the Security Development Lifecycle (SDL).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/memcpy-wmemcpy?view=vs-2017)"_.  Consider using more secure versions

Comment: @MickyD yeah `memcpy`  can suffer from buffer overflows and all associated shannigans however `CopyBlock` would be more suitable, though still unsafe by definition

Comment: Yes it's amazing they repeated the same pattern in CopyBlock ;)    +1

Comment: For future reference, Marshal.Copy worked well in my use-case. Ending up in an array was fine, all that was needed was casting my `byte* data` to an `IntPtr`.

Comment: @Loocid glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Span`, which has a constructor taking pointer as an argument, then use the [CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.copyto?view=net-6.0#system-span-1-copyto(system-span((-0)))) method.

You need to add reference to the [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) nuget package first.