# Are strings ALWAYS Little Endian Unicode?

Tags: c#, .net, string, unicode, encoding

I know that strings are stored in Unicode format. I have also heard that strings are ALWAYS Little Endian Unicode, even if the system is Big Endian. My question is this:

Are Strings represented in Big Endian Unicode IF the system is also Big Endian?

By the way, I'm using this for a small performance speedup when writing to a file that needs to be Little Endian Unicode.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to know??

Comment: My question is are strings stored internally as Big Endian Unicode IF the SYSTEM is also big endian?

Comment: it should be the same. what makes you concerned about this?

Comment: this sound like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): why are you interested in how .Net store the string (in memory, I assume)? unless you are planning to play with raw memory and unsafe code, this is not something you should worry about. or is it just plain (good) curiosity?

Comment: I don't know what Byte order use internally .NET for storing strings. Anyway for your case, I don't think you should know it to speed your code unless you measure and realize you have a real and meanigful performance problem. You should eventually use unsafe code, and in every case I doutb you will be able to beat .Net [UnicodeEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.unicodeencoding) class performance

Comment: Most text files applying the Unicode standard use the UTF-8 encoding. In UTF-8, endianness is not relevant. Endianness matters for UTF-16 and UTF-32. Which one are you using?

Comment: If you want to achieve a performance speedup by matching the encoding, you must have an in-depth understanding of .NET strings and you must have already put hours into optimizing everything else. If not, you gain much more by optimizing other things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) says:

> **I II.1.1.3 Character data type**
>
> A CLI char type occupies 2 bytes in memory and represents a Unicode code unit using UTF-16
> encoding.

There is no requirement that it be in a particular byte-order. And there are good reasons to expect that the byte order would match the byte order for other numeric types for the current architecture. I.e. on a big-endian machine, one would expect the `char` type to be stored as big-endian 16-bit values.

While it's not an authoritative document, I'll note that several people who have answered or commented on [How do I get a consistent byte representation of strings in C# without manually specifying an encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/472906) share this belief, i.e. that endianness of the `char` type depends on the platform architecture. There are several statements in the comments and answers to that question that claim that `char` is big-endian on big-endian systems.

It seems to me that if the endianness of your architecture is important, you would have access to a CLI implementation for a big-endian architecture and would be able to easily verify for yourself the byte order used for the `char` type. Have you made any effort to do such a verification?

All that said, it is very likely that you do not need to know the byte ordering for the `char` type. .NET provides character encoders for a wide variety of encodings, including both UTF16-LE and UTF16-BE. When using the `char` type itself, the byte ordering is irrelevant, and in situations where the byte ordering matters, you can force a specific ordering by using the appropriate `Encoding` type. If you feel that you have a situation which you believe is an exception to these general guidelines, it would be better to post a question describing exactly what that situation is and why you believe it's an exception to the general guidelines.