# how do convert string to byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, string, cryptography, arrays, byte

How do you get a byte array out of a string in C#? I would like to pass a string to [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx).

Comment: This is an exact duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/net-string-to-byte-array-c

Comment: Also a duplicate of this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241405/how-do-you-convert-a-string-to-a-byte-array-in-net

Comment: @Jaco Pretorius: Yes, I guess so, but I don't like the accepted answers in either of those. I like the accepted answer in this one. Always use UTF-8 unless you have a very good reason to use something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcd");
```

Comment: Can you explain why you used UTF8?

Comment: It's just an example. But UTF8 is very common. `Encoding.Default` would be another good example. See [Encoding Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.encoding_properties.aspx) for more Information

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
{
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding  encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(str);
}
```

Comment: Why create a new instance of UTF8Encoding when you can use Encoding.UTF8?

Comment: Can you explain why you used UTF8?

Answer (score 1):

Use [GetBytes(  )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Encoding.GetBytes` method.