# Convert String to Byte(0x??)

Tags: c#, winforms, byte, hex, sendkeys

I've made a window form application that send keys but in order to send keys I do this:

To send 'A' I have to write down MyFunction(0x41). 0x41 is a byte.

I can get the 41 as a string, but how do I convert it to a byte (of this format - 0x41)

Comment: [This may help][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802542/how-do-convert-string-to-byte-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast it to an integer type:

```
MyFunction((byte)'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Convert.ToByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k.aspx)