# Converting string to equivalent byte hex in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, hex

I have an incoming string `68016101061B4A60193390662046804020422044204000420040402060226024676DB16` and I want to convert into `0x68 0x01 0x61 0x01 0x06 0x1B 0x4A 0x60 0x0B 0x86 0xE8 0x46 0x04 0x68 0x04 0x02 0x04 0x22 0x04 0x42 0x04 0x00 0x04 0x20 0x04 0x40 0x02 0x06 0x02, 0x26 0x02 0x46 0x76 0xDB 0x16` but in bytes. I want to write these bytes into a serial port.

`port.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

**Update 1**

Below is the byte array that I am sending by hard coding it

```
var dataItems = new byte[] { 0x68, 0x01, 0x61, 0x01, 0x06, 0x1B, 0x4A, 0x60, 0x0B, 0x86, 0xE8, 0x46, 0x04, 0x68, 0x04, 0x02,
            0x04, 0x22, 0x04, 0x42, 0x04, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20, 0x04, 0x40, 0x02, 0x06, 0x02, 0x26, 0x02, 0x46 ,0x76 ,0xDB ,0x16 };
```

It gives me below array

[image]

How can I convert it?

Comment: What have you tried so far to convert it?

Comment: This classic question generally answers all my questions about this subject (even though the bulk of the question and it's answers deal with the opposite transformation) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/convert-integer-to-hexadecimal-and-back-again

Comment: This is already answered many times https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to do this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(\d{2})");

string aString = "040204220442040004200404020602260246";
string replaced = regex.Replace(aString, "x$1 ");
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1xWF5n)

EDIT
It seems like you need bytes instead of a string, you can use one of the Linq based answers suggested here or a simple loop:

```
if ((aString.Length % 2) != 0)
{
    // Handle invalid input
}

var bytes = new byte[aString.Length / 2];

int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < aString.Length; i += 2)
{
    string digits = aString.Substring(i, 2);
    byte aByte = (byte)int.Parse(digits, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    bytes[index++] = aByte;
}

port.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Note that if GC pressure became an issue, you could use `ReadOnlySpan<char>`.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2JgUQl)

Comment: It's in string I want it in bytes?

Comment: input can be in even and odd

Comment: @Faisal What do you mean? Bytes not consistently serialized as 2 chars? in this case there's no way to parse your string. For example, does 222 mean [2, 2, 2], [22, 2] or [2, 22]? Additionally, looking at the second entry (01) it seems like they are always serialized as 2 chars.

Comment: `222` means `2,2,2`.

Comment: My full string is `68016101061B4A601933906620468040204220442040004200404020602260246046676DB16`

Comment: Then how do you express 22 followed by a 2?

Comment: The number of bytes per char will be 1.

Comment: Your initial string was not hex, if you want a quick and clear answer please specify all the aspects of your question in the initial post, having to guess what you want is a waste of time for the ones replying

Comment: "The number of bytes per char will be 1" so the first 3 bytes in your string are [6, 8, 0]?

Comment: I want to send those bytes via serial port following the array that I suggested

Comment: So all your bytes are serialized as 2 consecutive characters, then the code should work

Comment: The fact that you want to send bytes to a port is irrelevant to the question, you just want to deserialize an array of bytes from a string

Comment: The string values `0402042204420400042004040206022602460466` can be less or more than that depending upon the parameters I want to read so I want to have a method that will convert any amount of strings not just a fixed amount

Comment: This code works with any string, provided each byte is encoded as 2 chars. Your example contains 71 chars and 71 is not a multiple of 2 therefore your input is invalid

Comment: Atually it's in `75`. Can I handle the odd numbers ?

Comment: The bytes up to position 16 (0 based) seem to follow the 2 chars -> 1 byte rule, then at position 16 , a '19' is supposed to be converted to  '0B': how is that conversion supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

In Linq:

```
string src = "040204220442040004200404020602260246";
string res = Enumerable.Range(0, src.Length)
                       .Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
                       .Aggregate<int, string, string>("", (s, i) => s + " 0x" + src.Substring(i, 2), (s) => s.Trim());
```

or - if the input string is very long - to better the performance:

```
 string res = Enumerable.Range(0, src.Length)
                        .Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
                        .Aggregate<int, StringBuilder, string>(new StringBuilder(), (sb, i) => sb.Append(" 0x").Append(src.Substring(i, 2)), (sb) => sb.ToString().Trim());
```

in both cases the `res` contains `"0x04 0x02 0x04 0x22 0x04 0x42 0x04 0x00 0x04 0x20 0x04 0x04 0x02 0x06 0x02 0x26 0x02 0x46"`

If you want the result as an array of bytes AND to handle input strings with an uneven number of digits as well it could be done as follwing:

```
string src = "040204220442040004200404020602260246";
if (src.Length % 2 == 1) src += "0";
byte[] res = Enumerable.Range(0, src.Length)
                       .Where(i => i % 2 == 0)
                       .Select(i => Byte.Parse(src.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: with odd number of values i am getting `Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length`

Comment: If the inputstring does not contains an even number of digits, what do you expect the result string to be? Depending on your expectations the linq expression can be fixed to support that scenario as well

Comment: string can be even or can be odd.

Comment: If your input string with an odd number of digits ends with on for instance 7, would you expect the last element in the result string to be 0x07 or 0x70 or simply 0x7?

Comment: Take my question example the last string is `16` and it's hex should be `0x16`

Comment: `01` will be `0x01`

Comment: If you input string has an uneven number of digits - for instance: "98567". How do you expect that string to be converted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214074/discussion-between-faisal-and-anders-hyldahl).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure LINQ, you can do something along the lines of

```
data
    .Select((x,i) => (Index: i, Value: x))
    .GroupBy(tuple => tuple.Index / 2, tuple => tuple.Value, (_,values) => "0x" + string.Join("",values))
    .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16))
    .ToArray();
```

if you want a ridiculous one-liner.

Comment: I want to have it in byte hex. Need to send data to a port

Comment: Changed to convert to a byte array.

Comment: Which byte would be halved then? In the example `12345` would I expect bits of `0x01 0x23 0x45`, `0x12 0x34 0x5`, or `0x12 0x34 0x50`. With an odd number of nibbles and no explanation for how to handle that odd nibble, there's no solid way of answering your question.

Comment: In my question, `68` ,`01` ..... `16`, each is of 1 byte. so `68` would become `0x68`, `01` into `0x01` and so on.

Comment: Yes, this solution works for an odd number of bytes. There will still be an even number of characters, which is what the `GroupBy` cares about

Comment: It's not giving me correct bytes. It should be `35` but I am getting `38`. You can see my updated question?